# Issues with creating and writing files to a directory

Tags: python, os.path

The code:

```py
import os.path
lines="hiya"

Question_2=input("Do you want a numeric summary report for? Y/N:")#If you input Y it will generate a single .txt file with number summary
if Question_2 == 'Y' or 'y':
    print("Q2-YES")
    OutputFolder = input('Name:')
    x = os.mkdir(OutputFolder)
    save_path = r'C:\Users\Owner\{}'.format(x)
    ReportName=input("Numeric Summary Report Name.txt:")#Name Your Report ".txt"
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, ReportName) 
    f=open(completeName,"w+")
    f.write(lines)
    f.close()
```

The traceback:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-83f8db356fab> in <module>
     10     ReportName=input("Numeric Summary Report Name.txt:")#Name Your Report ".txt"
     11     completeName = os.path.join(save_path, ReportName)
---> 12     f=open(completeName,"w+")
     13     f.write(lines)
     14     f.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\None\\testr.txt'
```

I am trying to write a conditional .txt file to a created folder in my directory, for some reason the folder is only created in my jupyter notebook, not in the desired directory, thus the "directory not found error". Does anyone have any idea how I can alter the code that it creates the folder in the desired directory? Thank you in advance

Comment: `if Question_2 == 'Y' or 'y':` is not correct. Either `if Question_2 == 'Y' or Question_w == 'y':` or `if Question_w.lower() == 'y':`

Comment: No it doesn't. Try typing `no` and it will still go into the rest of the code.

Comment: Why are you creating the subdirectory in the current directory, but then trying to use a subdirectory of `\Users\Owner` when writing the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because in line 8 you are assigning x to os.mkdir which does not return the filename, so pass the path you want to create the directory at instead.

This would be the answer you are looking for I think:

```py
import os.path

lines="hiya"
Question_2=input("Do you want a numeric summary report for? Y/N:")#If you input Y it will generate a  single .txt file with number summary
if Question_2 == 'Y' or 'y':
    print("Q2-YES")
    OutputFolder=input('Name:')
    save_path = r'C:\Users\Owner\{}'.format(OutputFolder)
    os.mkdir(save_path)
    ReportName=input("Numeric Summary Report Name.txt:")#Name Your Report ".txt"
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, ReportName) 
    f=open(completeName,"w+")
    f.write(lines)
    f.close()
```

I also made a few changes to simplify this code. The main thing is using the [with statement](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) here is the simplification:

```py
import os.path

lines="hiya"
Question_2 = input("Do you want a numeric summary report for? Y/N:") # If you input Y it will generate a  single .txt file with number summary
if Question_2 == 'Y' or 'y':
      OutputFolder = input('Enter Output folder name: ')
      save_path = os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\owner\\{}'.format(OutputFolder))
      os.mkdir(save_path)
      ReportName = input("Name of report file:") + ".txt" # Name Your Report ".txt"
      completeName = os.path.join(save_path, ReportName) 

      with open(completeName, "w") as output_file:
            output_file.write(lines)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `os.mkdir(save_path)`?

Comment: @Barmar save_path is defined after the creation call, though after looking at the code again I think your right that OP wants it to be at save_path not in the cwd

Comment: @dkh32 I just made an update, check the last set of posted code. That should work, I think there was something wrong with how you were saving the code out to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the line

```
x=os.mkdir(OutputFolder)
```

`os.mkdir` doesn't explicitly return a value so `x` becomes `None`.  When you inserted `x` into `save_path`, it got converted into the string `'None'`.  That created a path to a directory which doesn't exist and so Python couldn't create a file within it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to correct the problem?

Comment: It looks like you want to put `OutputFolder` in there.